# PHP - display image - just like Google image search

Tags: php, jquery

In my PHP page I want to display images (say 10 rows, 10 columns) - "more or less similar to, how it is displayed in Google image search"

I mean - when the page is opened the first page is filled with images, on scrolling down - it automatically bring the next set & so on.

I want it to be highly optimized. Can you suggest the best method for this in PHP - with examples.

Note: I am somewhat a beginner in PHP. With my limited knowledge I believe, jQuery may be better for this. (Do I need to use a json webservice - to bring in the image names from DB?). Your suggestions with samples (or help links for the same) is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Wait. You mean presentation of a list of images. CSS is already enough for that. Set add image to `float: left`. For scrolling then load, google "infinite scrolling"

Comment: Yup, you will need jquery loading images as you go down. Just google it and you will find many plugins to do that easily